# Appending a Dictionary to a List seems to overwrite instead

Tags: python-3.x

I know I am relatively close to getting this but I can't seem to work out why when I add another bidder the list only contains the latest dictionary even though I am appending to that list. I also tried .copy() to no avail, what am I missing here?

```
import os
from art import logo
clear = lambda: os.system('clear')
myFlag = True

print("Welcome to the Silent Auction....")
print(logo)

while myFlag:
    silent_dict = []

    name = input("Enter your name, Bidder: ")
    bid = int(input("Enter your Bid: £"))


    def add_new_bid(name, bid):
        new_entry = {"name": name, "bid": bid}
        silent_dict.append(new_entry)
        print(silent_dict)
        


    clear()
    add_new_bid(name, bid)

    more_bids = input("Are there any more bidders? Type Yes or No: ")

    if more_bids == "No":
        myFlag = False
        break
```

It's confusing because previously I've used the following code to do something similar so maybe I'm just bad at indentation?

```
travel_log = [
{
  "country": "France",
  "visits": 12,
  "cities": ["Paris", "Lille", "Dijon"]
},
{
  "country": "Germany",
  "visits": 5,
  "cities": ["Berlin", "Hamburg", "Stuttgart"]
},
]

def add_new_country(country, visits, cities):
    new_entry = {"country": country, "visits": visits, "cities": cities}
    travel_log.append(new_entry)

add_new_country("Russia", 2, ["Moscow", "Saint Petersburg"])
print(travel_log)
```

Comment: Can you please reduce this to a [mre] (e.g. no `from art import logo` needed, and fixed inputs instead of asking for input interactively)? Please also show in more detail what result you actually get and how it differs from what you want to get instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You initialize `silent_dict` to an empty list at the beginning of each loop iteration, which would erase the previous one the next time you enter a bid. You should run `silent_dict = []` before you enter your while loop.